# IOS 7 Spritekit Merging two nodes

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a turtle node and I want to add an overlay node right on the face of the turtle. 
I use this code to add an overlay to the turtle:

```
    NSString  *imagePath1 = [NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/someImageName.png"];
    SKSpriteNode *test = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[imagePath1 stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
    test.size = CGSizeMake(20, 20);
    [self.Turtle addChild:test];
```

When I add the code:
     test.position = CGPointMake(self.Turtle.position.x+30,self.Turtle.position.y);

the overlay will not appear.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to load the image from the documents directory?

Comment: I have and upgrade button and the user can take an image. When saved it is saved to documents directory and I load that image as a node.